# How to get annotations of Go language function?

Tags: go

How to get annotations of Go language function?
Example:

```
// @annotation1
// @annotation2
func Tags() string {
        return ""
}
```

How to get the "@annotation1" and "@annotation2"?

Comment: As far as I know those are just comments and there is no way to get them.

Comment: You can, however it involves the package [ast](https://godoc.org/go/ast).

Comment: @T.Claverie I mean, of course you can parse the source file as a string and extract comments but there is nothing formal like using reflect to get field tags as you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer, there is no native support for annotations in Golang. What's being used if tags, which you can get from the `reflect` package.

So, you do not have annotations in Go, and to my knowledge there is no library which provides them. Depending of what you want to do, usually tags are more than enough, and you can use the language's power to achieve the desired results.

It should be possible  to implement them as you can get the documentation strings, just like PHP does. However, in the big majority of cases it won't be necessary.

EDIT:

In Go, you have access to the documentation of structs, fields, methods, interfaces, functions (godoc isn't magical) through the `ast` package. However, it requires parsing the files, there is no function such as `type.getDocComments()` as in PHP.

So, an implementation is theoretically possible. However, the kind of annotations you're asking for are simply not part of Golang's philosophy. There are plenty of libraries that extensively use tags, but none use annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any native support for something that pulls specific tags from comments - however, the builtin functionality of [godoc](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) does pull from the comments directly adjacent to functions. If you are trying to build documentation, this may be useful.

In addition to godoc, I know that the [golang plugin for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047?pr=idea) pulls these comments as the help/documentation for inline completions and suggestions.

Hope this helps!